# Device Farm Vendors I have a meeting with them I need some questions

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, mobile, mobile-automation, reactjs

Firstly thank you for helping me with the previous question regarding device farm vendors.

I have a meeting with AWS next week and I'm stuck in regards to what questions I need to ask them.

- I know I want to find out if they perform testing with react native with detox as a testing model.  That's  essential.
- I know in need to find out how many handsets they have.
- What is their system in allocating time to perform testing?
- I want to know if they will provide onboarding and training support if required?

After that, I'm pretty much drawing a blank.

So I would really appreciate if anyone can come up with questions I could ask AWS (or any other vendor for that matter), that is an important criteria in selecting a device farm vendor.

I appreciate you so much and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

More questions:

1. Do you need one license for Android and an additional license for iOS ?
2. Is there a pricing option that includes both ?
3. What is the guaranteed turnaround time for support tickets ?
4. Who to contact if a device is asleep, locked, turned off, etc ?
5. What is the cost for dedicated mobile devices ?
6. How long are test results stored in the cloud ?
7. Is there an API that can be used to run tests ?

Comment: wish I could give you more than 1 up vote.  dude you are a legend :o)